# Android videoview - Work on emulator but not work on real divice

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have a recyclerview, item include videoview load video from url. In emulator, it working well. [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAdny.jpg)

But in device, it not load video [not load video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyGAm.jpg)

`onBindViewHolder` in my adapter:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    VideoModel item = VideoList.get(position);
    ((VHItem) holder).tvTittle.setText(item.getVideoTittle());
    ((VHItem) holder).tvTime.setText(item.getVideoTime());
    /***get clicked view and play video url at this position**/
    try {
        //play video using android api, when video view is clicked.
        String url = item.getVideoUrl(); // your URL here
        Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(url);
        ((VHItem) holder).videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
        //((VHItem) holder).videoView.seekTo(10);
        ((VHItem) holder).videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                mp.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {

                        /*
                         * add media controller
                         */

                        MediaController mc = new MediaController(mContext);
                        mc.setMediaPlayer(((VHItem) holder).videoView);
                        ((VHItem) holder).videoView.setMediaController(mc);
                        /*
                         * and set its position on screen
                         */
                        mc.setAnchorView(((VHItem) holder).videoView);
                    }
                });
                ((VHItem) holder).videoView.seekTo(10);
            }
        });


    } catch (
            Exception e)

    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

and list have url of video:

```
listVideo = new ArrayList<>();
    listVideo.add(new VideoModel(1,"BẠC LIÊU ĐẤT & NGƯỜI\n" +
            "Bạc Liêu hôm nay",
            "",
            "https://archive.org/download/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet_512kb.mp4",
            "Thứ Sáu, 29/06/2018, 08:20"));
    listVideo.add(new VideoModel(2,"BẠC LIÊU ĐẤT & NGƯỜI\n" +
            "Bạc Liêu quê hương tôi",
            "",
            "http://video.baobaclieu.vn/uploads/video/2017/05/11/N%C3%B4ng%20d%C3%A2n%20B%E1%BA%A1c%20Li%C3%AAu%20tr%C3%BAng%20m%C3%B9a%20gi%E1%BB%AFa%20c%C6%A1n%20%C4%91%E1%BA%A1i%20h%E1%BA%A1n%20-%20VTC.mp4",
            "Thứ Tư, 27/06/2018, 13:25"));
```

Does anybody know of a solution for this common problem that actually work?
Thankyou!

Comment: Would you be able to provide the specifications of the device you are running on?

Comment: Alas, this is all very common. Manufacturers either customize their Androids or they introduce bugs in it. I suspect this is going to be the case. I would suggest testing on a different brand, ideally a mainstream flagship model. If it works there, you can be pretty much sure, your phone is the culprit.

Comment: Also, by any chance, is your phone rooted? I've had flagship phones from Google and Samsung do all kinds of weird stuff with Camera1 and Camera2 when the phone is rooted. They randomly crashed, froze, etc.

Comment: I have tested on many different devices: Asus Zenfone2 android 5.0 API 21, Samsung Galaxy S8 android 8.0, Asus zenfone android 6.0. But the same result